# How to remove special characters from columns D and F?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in column D and F which might have special characters (, . / + &() etc.).
I want to remove the special characters if any and trim clean the columns.

```vb
Sub Splchrdel()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Exclusion")

Set Rng = ws.Range("D2:D", "F2:F")
    
With ws

    Rng.Replace What:=(("&", ",", ".", "/", "-", "+", "#", "!", "%", "(", ")", "*", _
      "'", "", "$")) Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
      :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    
    Rng("D2:D:", "F2:F").Trim.Clean

End Sub
```

Comment: `"D2:D"` and `"F2:F"` are not valid range references. They either need an ending row number, or to have the `2` removed. Also you probably need a loop.

Comment: Then how do I range it I want entire column D starting from D2 cell till end excel column D and  entire column F starting from F2 cell till end excel column F

Comment: [Find the last cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba). Or if you have a table (`ListObject`), use `.ListColumns("DF").DataBodyRange`.

Comment: I am not getting this please can u help it in codes I need to remove the special chars as mentioned in the question

Comment: Are there special characters in the header row?

Comment: yes thats why I want to code from range D2 and F2 till end of column D and F

Comment: To remove from columns D and F, or D to F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next way. `Replace` cannot receive multiple strings as `What` parameter. So, the strings must be placed in an array and then replace each array element. Another issue: "*" must be escaped, if you want to replace **only this character**. Otherwise, everything will be replaced with a  null string:

```
Sub Splchrdel()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, lastR As Long, arrWhat, El

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Exclusion")
    lastR = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'if F:F has different number of rows, another lastR should be calculated
    Set Rng = ws.Range("D2:D" & lastR & "," & "F2:F" & lastR) 'range only for D:D and F:F columns
   
    arrWhat = Array("&", ",", ".", "/", "-", "+", "#", "!", "%", "(", ")", "~*", "'", "", "$")
    For Each El In arrWhat
        Rng.Replace What:=El, replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Next El
    'Since `Clean` does not work on a range, an iteration is needed:
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Rng.cells
        cel.Value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(cel.Value))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks